# How many parity syndromes are there?

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

In [RAID 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_6), there is a parity scheme that allows 2 concurrent disk failures. This requires 2 ‘*syndromes*’, one of which is simply XOR, as used for RAID 5's only parity. In trying to find out [whether RAID 6 can support 3 or more parities](https://serverfault.com/questions/674478/can-raid-6-support-3-or-more-parities), it has been [disputed](https://serverfault.com/revisions/674499/4) that there even exist any other parity syndromes.
    I don't understand the maths for [computing RAID 6 parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#Computing_parity) or ‘[syndrome decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoding_methods#Syndrome_decoding)’ but I sort of make out that the 2 syndromes used in RAID 6 are just 2 of a very large group and that XOR is simply a special-case. Presumably the number of syndromes is something along the lines of an exponential function of the number of bits in a chunk (or other rapidly increasing combinatorial function such as factorial). I see something there about the bits being coëfficients of a polynomial, but this is somewhat over my head at the moment.
    If I'm correct that there *are* more than 2 parity syndromes, I'd like to know how to calculate the number of different syndromes for a given chunk size (or whatever parameters are required).

Comment: What's your question? I can't tell what your specific confusion/question is. Please edit to clarify, and ask just one question per question.  Is your question "Can RAID 6 support more than 3 or more parities?"  If so, edit to ask that question (and remove the stuff about how to number of syndromes etc.; that should be asked separately).  Be warned that you need to phrase the question carefully to be on-topic; questions about products or standard usage are off-topic.

Comment: Also, have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Concept and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction?  It seems clear that it would be *possible* to construct a RAID-6-like scheme with any number of "parities", using a suitable error-correcting code.  Is that what you are asking?  If not, what specifically is the technical question?  (I don't know whether that would technically be called RAID-6, but that's probably not on-topic here.  I don't know whether any products implement it, but that's off-topic here, too.)

Comment: Syndrome decoding is a particular (efficient) technique for decoding [Linear Block codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code).  RAID 6 is _defined_ to be a particular linear block code with 2 parity bits.  You could define your own linear block code with an arbitrary number of parity bits.  For correcting more than 1 error you would want something like a [Hadamard code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code#Example:_Hadamard_codes).  (It wouldn't be RAID 6 anymore, of course.)